# call QuickAction in test class

Tags: unit-test

In class  implements `QuickAction.QuickActionDefaultsHandler` and below method is just blank need to cover in test class which parameter I can pass for cover this.

```
mailmsg.onInitDefaults('whats need which parameter Enter');
```

---

```
global void onInitDefaults(QuickAction.QuickActionDefaults[] defaults) {

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do something like

```
List<QuickAction.QuickActionDefaults> defaults = new List<QuickAction.QuickActionDefaults>();
mailmsg.onInitDefaults(defaults );
```

This will cover the blank method.